# Filter '*.modeshape' files in JCR_SQL2

Tags: modeshape

How do I exclude the modeshape files when querying a FileSystemSource?

They all have `jcr:createdBy 'null'` but the following causes a null pointer exception when I query:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:file] where [jcr:createdBy] != 'null'
```

This works ok:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:file] where [jcr:createdBy] = '<anonymous>'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file on the file system named "foo.txt", ModeShape may place a "foo.txt.modeshape" file in the same directory. The ".modeshape" files contain the extra properties that were added to the "nt:file", "nt:folder", and "nt:resource" nodes.

Generally, your File System connector should not be exposing such files to the JCR repository. If it is, then you've likely misconfigured the "extraPropertiesBehavior" setting on the connector. For details, see the [connector documentation for ModeShape 2.8](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE28/File+System+Connector). (Note that if you're using a custom properties factory, then you need to set the "exclusionFilter" to ignore the ".modeshape" files.

Comment: I just had a look at extraPropertiesBehaviour and that's about whether or not .modeshape files are stored next to the nt:file/nt:folder objects.

However adding the mode:exclusionPattern="^.*\.(modeshape)$"  mentioned in the doc you linked did the job.